# Javascript setTimeout performance vs manual check

Tags: javascript, performance, webgl, settimeout

I'm writing a WebGL game and I am curious if it would be better performance wise to implement my game's events by checking if they should occur at every update of `requestAnimationFrame` (using `Date.now()`) or by setting timeouts (using `setTimeout()`).

Note that the events are usually about 100ms apart.

My major concern is that `setTimeout` does not waste CPU when idle (waiting for the next event) and if I do the check at every update ill be doing computations that wouldn't happen if I was using setTimeout

Comment: This is what `requestAnimationFrame` was invented for. The check you make each time it is called (typically, has a certain number of milliseconds elapsed since the last time) will take few microseconds.

Comment: are these "events" you're checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need events, create [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) and use eventListeners.

If you need to check at every call of rAF that a condition has changed to perform some action, just do the checks in the rAF loop.

Note : you don't need and **should avoid** creating a new Date Object at each call ; there is a TimeStamp passed as the only argument of the requested function through rAF, use this.

```
function update(timestamp){...};   
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Using setTimeout at a high rate will just make an useless call to the timedout function that will be pushed on top of the stack of tasks to perform.

Embedding the checks at the top of the rAF loop is just as good.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the right thing to do is use [requestAnimationFrame](http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/).

---

If you are already in a requestAnimationFrame, I think it is a much better idea to check the current time and any pending events, and essentially do any work that you can.

A `setTimeout` entails something very like a context switch, which is a needless expense, and of course, if the events result in updating the screen, you would either have to do the update "now", or arrange to do it in the next requestAnimationFrame, both unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion (if there is any). I have already updated my question.
I am using requestAnimationFrame for drawing.
The question is should I manually check the events in the same update cycle or should i set timeouts. (and why)

Comment: If a change occurs caused by an event it changes the state of an object.
This state changes the way the object is rendered on the next update. (No additional logic is required)
But I understand your point. My major concern is that setTimeout does not waste cpu when idle (waiting for the next event) and if I check the event at every update ill be wasting cpu

Comment: I agree of course with using RAF, but am puzzled by the following statement: *A `setTimeout` entails something very like a context switch*. both RAF and `setTimeout` use callbacks, so there is no essential difference in their behavior as regards "context switching", whatever you mean by that. The difference is that RAF is more precise and is called at optimal times during the browser's workflow.

Comment: setTimeout (in contrast to Date.now(), not RAF) necessarily entails returning control from the browser's internal function to its Javascript interpreter, and in that way, resembles a context switch.  How expensive that really is I don't know, but it cannot be less expensive than _not_ doing it.